# How to use find_element_by_id() in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I am trying to set my username in in gmail browser by using python2.6.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium import WebElement;
driver = webdriver.Ie();
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");

WebElement uname = driver.find_element(by=By,id("Username:"));

uname.sendKeys("chakry.gosetty");
```

With the above code I am getting

```
WebElement uname= driver.find_element(by=By,id("Username:"));
SyntaxError : Invalid syntax.
```

Please help me.

Rgds,
G.Chakravarthy

Answer (score 16):

How about...

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get('http://www.gmail.com')

driver.find_element_by_id('Email').send_keys('chakry.gosetty')
```

- you don't need semicolons as line terminators in python :)
- also, the username field ID is actually `Email` not `Username:`

Answer (score 7):

A guess: Apart from the other obvious syntax errors, you don't import By. How about this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
uname = driver.find_element(By.ID,value="...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Isaac's answer is correct with a small modification. The email field on gmail is an input type field that does not have a reliable id. I would go with below syntax to identify that field.

> driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type='email']')

Since your question was about how to find an element using ID the answer is

> driver.find_element_by_id("idLocatorValue")