# Proper syntax for find_element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to build a web scraper in Selenium. The first thing I want the script to do is to log in with my credentials into a database. Thus, I attempted to use find_element in order locate the user id/password entry fields.

However, when I used find_element, I was thrown the following error: "By" is not defined Pylance (reportUndefinedVariable).

I've read the Selenium 4 documentation at selenium.dev, but I'm not sure what exactly has gone wrong here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service as IEService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import IEDriverManager


def test_driver_manager_chrome():
    service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

    driver.quit()

#open the browser

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window

#navigate to the website

driver.get("URL")

#log in 

userID = driver.find_element(By.ID, "_58_login")
```

Comment: please try : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7732002

Comment: Apologies but the answer appears out of date, and it did not resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution - By needs to be imported separately. Thus a separate line must be added to this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import by
```